# Custom EditorFor Template and htmlAttributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, editorfortemplate

I'm trying to use EditorFor custom templates.

I want to create a Int32 and decimal templates to render the inputs with some validations.

This is what I'm trying

```
@model int?

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model, null, new { @type="text", @oninput = "this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')" } )
```

And I call it like

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ExampleIntField)
```

It renders an `<input type="text", oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')"`

To here everything works, but when I try to pass extra htmlAttributes like `readonly` I don't understand how I must receive it in EditorFor template.

Example

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ExampleIntField, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly" } } )
```

I tried this I got the exact same `<input type="text", oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')"` rendered without `readonly attribute`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.Object%29) of `EditorFor()` that passes the object as `additionalViewData`. You can read that within the template from the `ViewDataDictionary`

```
@model int?
@{ var attributes = ViewData["htmlAttributes"]; } // returns { @readonly = "readonly" }
```

which you could then merge with your existing attributes and use in the `TextBoxFor()` method.

```
@{
    var htmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(attributes);
    htmlAttributes.Add("oninput", "this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')";
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model, htmlAttributes)
```

Note that `TextBoxFor()` generates `type="text"` so there is no need to add it again. In addition, you do not need the leading `@` unless its a reserved keyword (for example `@class = "..."`)

Comment: Thanks! you are awesome!