# How to extract single value from htmlAttributes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've this EditorFor:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyDecimalValue, new { htmlAttributes = new { additionalClass = (Model.OperationType == EDIT ? "disabled" : "") } })
```

Which I render in this way:

```
@model decimal?

@{
    var classes = new { @class = "form-control is-decimal ";
    var htmlAttributes = ViewData["htmlAttributes"] ?? "" };
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, classes)
```

I need, once `additionalClass` is not empty or null, to concatenate its value with the `@class` string.

How would you do this? Not sure how to get `additionalClass` value from `htmlAttributes`, into the partial.

`htmlAttributes["additionalClass"]` doesn't works.

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50061954/custom-editorfor-template-and-htmlattributes/50062194#50062194) for an option for merging the attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an anonymous type so you can use reflection. For example:

```
private object GetPropertyValue(object item, string propertyName)
{
    var propertyInfo = item.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    return propertyInfo.GetValue(item);
}
```

And use like this:

```
var additionalClass = GetPropertyValue(htmlAttributes, "additionalClass");
```

An additional way would be to use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic htmlAttributes = ViewData["htmlAttributes"];
var additionalClass = (string)htmlAttributes.additionalClass;
```